# Spring Cloud Data Flow with Docker images from private repo - imagePullSecrets not being used. Cant Pull image

Tags: docker, kubernetes, spring-cloud-dataflow

So I am unable to Launch a **custom task application** stored in a **private docker repo**. All my docker images in Kubernetes come are pulled from this private repo. So the **imagePullSecrets** works fine but it seems it is not being used by Spring Cloud Dataflow when deploying the task to Kubernetes. If I inspect the pod there is no imagepullSecret set.

The error I get is:

xxxxx- no basic auth credentials
[image]

The server has been deployed with the ENV variable which the guide states will fix this

```
    - name: SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_KUBERNETES_IMAGE_PULL_SECRET
      value: regcred
```

I have even tried to add custom properties on a per-application bases

I have read through the guide [HERE](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_private_docker_registry)

I am running the following versions:

Kubernetes 1.15 &

[image]

I have been stuck on this issue for weeks and simply can't find a solution. I'm hoping somebody has seen this issue and managed to solve it before?

Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Have you done this? https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

Comment: Yes, I have a k8s secret named regcred  for authenticating against my private repo. All nonspring Cloud dataflow images used in the cluster uses this secret perfectly fine. If I open the pod definition of these other pods they all have the imagePullSecrets set to regcred but those deployed by Spring Cloud dataflow do not have this property. I was hoping that setting the environment variable as stated in the doc would cause the deployer to set this on deployment to k8s..

Answer (score 1):

So I found if I do the following it pulls the image (it seems i put this in the wrong place as the documentation doesn't clearly specify where and how)

[image]

But using the global environment variable as stated above does not seem to work still

Answer (score 1):

Using the environment variable `SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_KUBERNETES_IMAGE_PULL_SECRET` also didnt work for me.

An alternative that made it work in my case is adding the following to the `application.yaml` of the SCDF Server in Kubernetes:

application.yaml

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    dataflow:
      task:
        platform:
          kubernetes:
            accounts:
              default:
                imagePullSecret: <your_secret>
```

or, when you are using a custom SCDF image like i do, you can of course specify it as argument:

deployment.yaml

```yaml
[...]
command: ["java", "-jar", "spring-cloud-dataflow-server.jar"]
args:
  - --spring.cloud.dataflow.task.platform.kubernetes.accounts.default.imagePullSecret=<your_secret>
[...]
```

More details on https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/